# How do return an enum in a typedef of function pointer?

Tags: c, enums, function-pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum bool
{
  true, false
};

typedef bool
(*compare_fun) (int, int);
```

I get an error when I enter the above code. How do I make a function pointer that needs to return a boolean?

Comment: are you sure that you want `true, false` in this order? You would get `true=0,false=1` which is really nonstandard.

Comment: Any reason you can't use [`stdbool.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdbool.h), which is part of standard C (C99)?

Comment: Never ever declare your own Boolean type, this calls for trouble. Either use what C99 gives you, namely `_Bool` (and `bool`, `true` and `false` from `stdbool.h` as Matthew mentions) or use the old time version and return `int`.

Comment: Also, I think it good practise to capitalise enum values.

Comment: @Blank Xavier: I think it's a bad practice to capitalize things that aren't preprocessor macros.

Comment: The problem is that they are visually indistinguishable from variables.  I capitalize everything which can be confused with a variable which is not a variable (ditto for functions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it should be `typedef enum bool (*compare_fun)(int, int);` :)

Also make sure your implementation doesn't have predefined `bool` `true` and `false`

Note that in C++ when you define an enum, class or struct, say with name A, then you can declare a variable of type A like

```
A var;
```

or

```
class A var; //or struct A var; or enum A var;
```

in C, only the second syntax is valid.
That's why they usually make a typedef. like this

```
typedef enum {true, false} bool;
```

in this case you can use your original syntax :

```
typedef bool (*p) (int, int);
```

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
typedef enum 
{
    true, false
} bool;

bool
(*compare_fun) (int, int);
```

Comment: @Blank Xavier: By that reasoning, you'd never use `typedef` anywhere.  `typedef` always creates an alias to an *existing* type.

Comment: True; there is more to it than that.  The problem is that even when typedefed, *you still need to know the underlying type to use it*.  So typedefing acts and acts only to make reading the code harder, since you have to look up and then remember the real type while you're reading.

Comment: @Blank Xavier - I don't get your point. I can use the 'bool' type easily, and return 'true' or 'false' without additional keywords or anything tricky. To use an 'int' you have to have some understanding of what values an 'int' can have. If the type you create with 'typedef' is sensible and intuitive, it makes sense.

Comment: Everyone knows the types which are a part of C.  Those are part of what your brain learns to read when it learns C.  But every additional type is not generic - even enum bool - and so every new type is an incremental burden on the reader, requiring an increment of attention and memory, which subtracts from that which is available to comprehend the code.

Comment: The only way to get round this is to operate on the typedef *only* with function calls, such that the user literally does not need to know the underlying type.  If the underlying type must be remembered (which is not the case for int, since it is what it is and it is part of C, rather than part of an individuals code) then it is a burden.

Comment: That would just mean the user has to remember (or look up) the function calls instead. If 'enum bool' is an additional type, then so is 'struct x'. I think we're fairly used to additional types and the minor burden that places on our memory (especially when working within a particular code base for a period of time). I'd rather that than the fairly useless extra typing.